# How do I make my object disappear when it hits my character in my game?

Tags: arrays, image, object, processing, 2d-games

I'm trying to make a game where my character (Homer Simpson) has to collect falling objects (donuts) and avoid falling toxic-tanks. Right now my score increments every time he gets a donut, but I wish to make the donut disappear afterwards. Can anyone help me with that?

This is my code so far:

```
PImage bg2; //background image

PImage homer; //image of homer

homer homer1; 

int numberOfToxic = 3; //number of falling toxic tanks

int numberOfDonut = 3; //number of falling donuts

int score; //the score

Toxic[] toxic; //array for the toxic that will fall
PImage t;

Donut[] donut; //array for the donuts that will fall
PImage d;



void setup() {
  size(600,500); //size of the window
  bg2 = loadImage("bg2.jpg"); //uploading the background image
  homer = loadImage("homer.gif"); //uploading the character image
  t = loadImage("toxictank.png");
  d = loadImage("donut.png");
  PFont louiseFont; 
  louiseFont = loadFont("chalk.vlw"); //loading the font I've chosen
  textFont(louiseFont); //the current font being used in the game




  toxic = new Toxic[numberOfToxic];
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfToxic; i++) {
    toxic[i] = new Toxic();
}

  donut = new Donut[numberOfDonut];
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDonut; i++) {
    donut[i] = new Donut();
}

score = 0; //the score starts at 0

}

void draw() {
  background(bg2); 
  homer1 = new homer(mouseX-70, 350, 140, 150, homer); //mouseX makes the hero     move on the x axis and 350 defines where it is on the y axis. -70 center the mouse     on the image/hero
  homer1.drawHomer(); //call the function homer(hero)

//Making the taxictanks fall
  for(int i = 0; i < toxic.length; i++) {
    toxic[i].update();
    toxic[i].drawToxic();
    if(toxic[i].position.y > 500) {
      toxic[i].reset();
    }
  }
//Making the donuts fall
  for(int i = 0; i < donut.length; i++) {
    donut[i].update2();
    donut[i].drawDonut();
    if(donut[i].position2.y > 500) {
      donut[i].reset2();
    }

//Collecting points if Homer eats donuts
   if(abs(donut[i].position2.y - homer1.y) <= 2 && abs(donut[i].position2.x-40 - homer1.x)<=40) {
    score ++;
     println("ok");

   }  
}

  fill(#0D128B); //color of text
  textSize(20); //size of text
    text("SCORE: " + nf(score, 1), 20, 40); //score points - tells how to use     the text in the game
}

 //class with height, width x, y positions and the hero image
class homer {
  int x;
  int y;
  int hWidth;
  int hHeight;
  PImage homer;

homer(int x, int y, int hWidth, int hHeight, PImage homer) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.hWidth = hWidth;
  this.hHeight = hHeight;
  this.homer = homer;
}

void drawHomer() {
  image(this.homer, this.x, this.y, this.hWidth, this.hHeight);
}
}



class Toxic { //all the variables for toxic
  PImage t;
  PVector position;
  float speed;
  float size;

  //constructor of toxic
  Toxic() {
    t = loadImage("toxictank.png");
    position = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    speed = 4;
    size = 20;
  }

  void update() {
    position.y += speed;

  }

  void drawToxic() {
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      image(t, position.x, position.y);

    }
  }

  void reset() {
  position.x = random(width);
  position.y = 0 - 50;
  speed = 4;
  size = 20;
}
}




class Donut { //all variables for donut
  PImage d;
  PVector position2;
  float speed2;
  float size2;
  boolean falling;
  int timeToDisplay;
  int fallingSpeed;

  Donut() { //constructor of donut
    d = loadImage("donut.png");
    position2 = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    speed2 = 4;
    size2 = 40;
    falling = false;
    timeToDisplay = (int)random(2.60);
    fallingSpeed = (int)random(2.5);
   }

  void update2() {
    position2.y += speed2;
  }

  void drawDonut() {
    for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
      image(d, position2.x, position2.y);
    }
  }

  void reset2() {
  position2.x = random(width);
  position2.y = 0 - 50;
  speed2 = 4;
  size2 = 20;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the variables in the instance of `Donut` so that it goes back to the top of the screen, or isn't drawn at all. You already have a `reset2()` function that does that. Something like this:

```
if(abs(donut[i].position2.y - homer1.y) <= 2 && abs(donut[i].position2.x-40 - homer1.x)<=40) {
    score ++;
    donut[i].reset2();
    println("ok");
}
```